# I want to disable click property after I click once

Tags: javascript, toggle

**I want to disable clickability after the first click ** I used this code but did not work.

```
let counter = 0;

inputOptions.forEach((inputOptions) => {
    inputOptions.addEventListener("click", () => {

        inputOptions.classList.toggle("active");
        if (inputOptions.classList.contains("active")) {
            inputOptions.style.pointerEvent = 'none';
        }

        if (inputOptions.innerHTML == "Dhaka") {
            counter++;
        } else { counter = 0; }
    })

})

function getResult() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No of Correct answer:" + counter;
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your html

Comment: If you only want to use it once there is a *one()* method that removes listener after first click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass parameter `{ once: true }`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((inputOptions) => {
      inputOptions.addEventListener("click", (el) => {
        console.log(inputOptions)
      }, { once: true })
})
```

```html
<button>A</button>
<button>B</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is sample of code for disabled button after once click.
You need to define id in html then access button like below code.

this is just sample of working code. you need to get idea from this then implement according to your requirement

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript - Disable Button after Click using JavaScript Function.</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function disableButton(btn){
                document.getElementById(btn.id).disabled = true;
                alert("Button has been disabled.");
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="text-align: center;">
        <h1>JavaScript - Disable Button after Click using JavaScript Function.</h1>
        <p><input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click to disable button." onclick="disableButton(this)"</p>

    </body>

</html>
```